# c++, control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

I get an error(control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]) when compiling this code:
It should return true if there are no gaps in the string and false if there are gaps.

```
bool isSafeBridge(string bridge){
    for (int i = 0; i < bridge.length(); i++)
    {
        if (bridge[i] == ' ')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    cout<<isSafeBridge("####");
}
```

Comment: What should it return if `bridge.length()` is `0`?

Comment: I think at least one of the five duplicates should be enough  to answer your question, and what you need to do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the string is completely empty, the for loop will never run, and no return statement will happen.

Figure out whether you want `false` or `true` for an empty string (probably `true`, since an empty string has no gaps), and return that at the end of the function.

Comment: And if not `return true;` or `return false;`, there's also `throw std::logic_error("there is no bridge");`

Answer (score 3):

First, `isSafeBridge` does not do what you want it to do. In **each** iteration, it returns either `false` or `true`. That means, in the first iteration, if the character is not a space, the function will return `true`. That ends the function call. It will not go on to examine the other characters.

If the current character is a space, you want to return `false`, as there is a gap. If the character is not a space, you want to continue examining other characters. Only after **all** characters have been examine should you return `true`, if there have been no spaces.

And, while the function also returns a value in each iteration of the loop, it is possible it does not return a value. That can happen if it is passed a string of zero length. Then there are no iterations of the loop, so neither the `return false;` nor the `return true;` is executed. Control flows beyond the loop to the end of the function, where there is no `return` statement, and that is why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

What should happen if `bridge.length()` is zero?

Is that a safe bridge because it has no gaps? Is it not a safe bridge because it's not a bridge?

The compiler certainly doesn't know the answer to this.